# Sort takes longer on integer column?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

Database is postgres.

I have two queries on same table. The two queries are exactly the same except that one use a text column siteid in With records, and the other use smallint column sitegid in With records. But explain analyze returned much longer estimation on the query that use smallint sitegid. It doesn't make sense to me. Did anyone know why?

I attached part of the explain analyze output here for these two queries. They are exactly the same except actually time used for groupAggregate. Desperate for help. Thank you!

Query is like:

```
With records as (...)
SELECT source, siteid,  observed_contingency_row, forecast_contingency_col,
                  count(*),sum(diff) as sum_error 
FROM records 
GROUP BY source, siteid,  observed_contingency_row, forecast_contingency_col 
ORDER BY source, siteid,  observed_contingency_row, forecast_contingency_col
```

It is a very long query and could not post all of it here.

Output from explain analyze are:

```
->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.08..0.11 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=14.880..14.894 rows=15 loops=1)
     ->  Sort  (cost=0.08..0.09 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=14.876..14.877 rows=15 loops=1)
           Sort Key: records.observed_contingency_row, records.forecast_contingency_col
           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
           ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.03..0.07 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=14.775..14.869 rows=15 loops=1)
                 Group Key: records.source, records.siteid, records.observed_contingency_row, records.forecast_contingency_col
                 ->  Sort  (cost=0.03..0.04 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=14.762..14.773 rows=176 loops=1)
                       Sort Key: records.source, records.siteid, records.observed_contingency_row, records.forecast_contingency_col
                       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 38kB
                       ->  CTE Scan on records  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=10.664..14.306 rows=176 loops=1)
```

and

```
->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.08..0.11 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=1558.508..1558.516 rows=15 loops=1)
     ->  Sort  (cost=0.08..0.09 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=1558.503..1558.503 rows=15 loops=1)
           Sort Key: records.observed_contingency_row, records.forecast_contingency_col
           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
           ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.03..0.07 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=1558.403..1558.495 rows=15 loops=1)
                 Group Key: records.source, records.siteid, records.observed_contingency_row, records.forecast_contingency_col
                 ->  Sort  (cost=0.03..0.04 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=1558.388..1558.407 rows=176 loops=1)
                       Sort Key: records.source, records.siteid, records.observed_contingency_row, records.forecast_contingency_col
                       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 38kB
                       ->  CTE Scan on records  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=7.106..1557.779 rows=176 loops=1)
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Put the query in the question.